# Adding PullToRefresh to my application not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I went through the example of [Pulltorefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) library. They have implemented it to fit a TableViewController class. But mine is a UIViewController, and i am adding a TableView in it.

The problem is that i am unable to integrate the Pulltorefresh features to my application.

In there demo application they have coded it like

```
@interface DemoTableViewController : PullRefreshTableViewController {
```

in my view i have it as this,

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UiTableVIewControllerDelegate,....>{
```

I have no way of adding `PullRefreshTableViewController` to it. So how can i make this work ?

note: i am using `UIViewController` in my appplication because i have several other UI components in my application, the `tableView` is only displayed on top of the screen.

Comment: Are you creating the table view directly without a table view controller?

Comment: I have created a UIViewCOntroller and then i am adding a TableView to it.

Comment: You do understand about inheritance and composition, right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating your `UITableView`, instantiate a `PullRefreshTableViewController` and then add its `tableView` to your main `UIViewController` object.

This has some more chance to work correctly, although it's just a guess. Anyway, it should not be that complicated to try out. Hope it helps.

EDIT:

if you would like to include exactly the same table view controller as in the demo you mentioned, I would do like this (memory management is up to you):

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
   ...
   DemoTableViewController* pullViewCtrl;
   ....
}
@end

@implementation myViewController

....

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    pullViewCtrl = [DemoTableViewController alloc....];
    [self.view addSubview:pullViewCtrl.view];
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   ....
   [pullViewCtrl viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   ....
   [pullViewCtrl viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

@end
```

Comment: Ok, then i will not be able to use `[self.tableview reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

check out this ,it shows how to subclass uitableview instead of uitableviewcontroller

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/